# Store values from a big .txt file into an array

Tags: php, arrays, file, parsing

I have a big .txt file (73 thousand lines) and i need to store the data from that file in an array.

Here is an example of how the file looks, it just repeats in this fashion, every line looks like this.

```
2016-05-27 11:04:16: QParRFSum=1574.00 QParRFSumMean=6.05 QParSuspSum=83.00
2016-05-27 11:14:07: QParRFSum=1537.00 QParRFSumMean=5.91 QParSuspSum=96.00
2016-05-27 11:14:07: QParRFSum=1537.00 QParRFSumMean=5.91 QParSuspSum=96.00
2016-05-27 11:24:07: QParRFSum=1405.00 QParRFSumMean=5.40 QParSuspSum=0.00
2016-05-27 11:24:07: QParRFSum=1405.00 QParRFSumMean=5.40 QParSuspSum=0.00
2016-05-27 11:34:06: QParRFSum=1533.00 QParRFSumMean=5.90 QParSuspSum=89.00
2016-05-27 11:34:06: QParRFSum=1533.00 QParRFSumMean=5.90 QParSuspSum=89.00
```

And I would like to put this into an array with keys like this:

```
Array (
[0] =>
(
    [date] => 2016-05-27
    [time] => 11:04:16
    [QParRFSum] => 1574.00
    [QParRFSumMean] => 6.05
    [QParSuspSum] => 83.00
)
[1] =>
(
    [date] => 2016-05-27
    [time] => 11:14:07
    [QParRFSum] => 1537.00
    [QParRFSumMean] => 5.91
    [QParSuspSum] => 96.00
)
[2] =>
(
    [date] => 2016-05-27
    [time] => 11:14:07
    [QParRFSum] => 1537.00
    [QParRFSumMean] => 5.91
    [QParSuspSum] => 96.00
)
)
And so on...
```

How would i do this in the best way, having performance in mind?

My thought was to go through it line by line with the file() function and a foreach loop. And then somehow process it into the array structure I want. Something like this:

```
$txt=file('path/to/file');
foreach($txt as $line)
{
   $RFAValues[] = $line;
}
```

Is this the way to go, or is there a better way which will give me better performance?

Comment: I barely believe you need all 73k rows at once. And if so, you do not need it in array. Why you do not just read the file, put it into DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote from my memory but use something like that

```
$file = file_get_contents('file.txt');
$list = explode(PHP_EOL, $file);
$_temp = [];
foreach ( $list as $row )
{
    $_explode = explode(' ', $row);
    $_temp[] = [
        'date' => $_explode[0],
        'time' => rtrim($_explode[1], ':'),
        'QParRFSum' => $_explode[2],
        'QParRFSumMean' => $_explode[3],
        'QParSuspSum' => $_explode[4]
    ];
}

var_dump( $_temp );
```

Comment: You should use for example 'QParRFSum' => explode("QParRFSum=", $_explode[2])[1] etc.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, if you're handling *huge* files, I'd use a combination of [`generators`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php) and [`file streams`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php). So you have your stream, and you turn that in to an array *on demand* using generators, so that you don't run out of memory. Maybe something like this

```
function readFromFile($fileName) {
    $handle = @fopen("/tmp/inputfile.txt", "r");
    while (($line = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {
        //Process Line
        yield $line;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```